# Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

The full error message is:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 23 of the expression ["Serious Outcome Rate","Hospitalization Rate"] starting at [,"Hospitalization Rate"].

I have a string of data converted to an array that I'm trying to then export using the Angular ng-csv directive. A console.log of the data in array form displays the following:

> [""Product Name(s)"", ""Serious Outcome Rate"", ""Hospitalization Rate"", ""IME Serious Rate"", ""DME Serious Rate"", ""STALEVO"", ""0.004234647"", ""0.002063946"", ""0.0058004"", ""0.00050709"", ""EXELON"", ""0.004005612"", ""0.001674727"", ""0.00509257"", ""0.00044815"", ""COMTAN"", ""0.000867331"", ""0.000536579"", ""0.00129375"", ""0.00024444"", ""AZILECT"", ""0.000545076"", ""0.000394459"", ""0.00102432"", ""0.00025449"", ""PARLODEL"", ""0.000375725"", ""0.000230684"", ""0.0009696"", ""0.00012616"", ""ARTANE"", ""0.00035673"", ""0.000210014"", ""0.00078005"", ""0.00033002"", ""REQUIP XL"", ""0.000318172"", ""0.000191126"", ""0.00042839"", ""0.0000432"", ""MIRAPEX"", ""0.000217509"", ""0.000144021"", ""0.00029248"", ""0.00004242"", ""SINEMET"", ""0.000177481"", ""0.000112357"", ""0.00019475"", ""0.00004321"", ""REQUIP"", ""0.000151958"", ""0.000099112"", ""0.00020999"", ""0.00001765"", ""SINEMET CR"", ""0.000135481"", ""0.000090321"", ""0.00013548"", """", ""SYMMETREL"", ""0.000083309"", ""0.000045017"", ""0.00017632"", ""0.0000544"", ""MIRAPEX ER"", ""0.000074176"", ""0.000074176"", ""0.00004945"", """", ""COGENTIN"", ""0.00005202"", ""0.000020805"", ""0.00003236"", ""0.00000694""]

Here's my code:

```
    var csvArray = csvData.split(',');
    csvArray.pop();

    var fp = grid.$root.find(".ng-grid-buttons");
    var csvDataLinkPrevious = grid.$root.find('.ng-grid-buttons .csv-data-link-span');
    var csvDataLinkPrevious2 = grid.$root.find('.ngHeaderButton2');
    if (csvDataLinkPrevious != null) {csvDataLinkPrevious.remove(); csvDataLinkPrevious2.remove(); }
    var csvDataLinkHtml = "<div class='ngHeaderButton2'></div>";
    csvDataLinkHtml += "<span type='button' ng-csv='"+csvArray+"' filename='data.csv' class='csv-data-link-span'><i class='fa fa-file-excel-o excel-icon'></i></span>";

    $(function() {
      angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        var link = $compile(csvDataLinkHtml);
        csvDataLinkHtml = link(scope);
        fp.append(csvDataLinkHtml);
      });
    });
```

If I remove one set of quotes from each element in the array, the error message is slightly different:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Outcome' is an unexpected token at column 9 of the expression [Serious Outcome Rate,Hospitalization Rate] starting at [Outcome Rate,Hospitalization Rate].

Comment: What about replacing the inner quotes with single quotes?

Comment: that did it! thanks dan, no more error messages. now just need to figure out why the directive isn't reading my array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing inner quotes with single quotes as dan08 suggested solved the issue.